# Upgrading to Django 1.7: table prefix using `class_prepared`

Tags: django, unit-testing, database-migration, django-1.7

I'm at a new job. One of my predecessors used [the class_prepared signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/signals/#class-prepared) to apply a prefix to all the table names, i.e. `django_content_type` is `oursite_django_content_type`. I think this was unnecessary and ill advised (I looked at doing this at a previous job and did not), as the documentation says that `class_prepared` is an implementation detail. Well -- now it's a problem.

The site seems to work okay (I didn't thoroughly test it yet) but I can't run our unit tests. This is because the migrations are a core feature now and [the contenttypes migration defines the db_table_name](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/contrib/contenttypes/migrations/0001_initial.py#L23).

I dropped some debugging statements and this is the sequence of events.

1. `class_prepared` is run for `contenttypes` -- the db_table_name for the class is altered to `oursite_django_content_type`.
2. The **migration** is run and it creates the `django_content_type` table.
3. Tests are run and they can't find `oursite_django_content_type`.

I think I'm going to have to migrate the tables to their default values, but -- Does anyone have a suggestion so that I might put this off so that my successor will have to deal with it?

Comment: `Does anyone have a suggestion so that I might put this off so that my successor will have to deal with it?` Lol. You can not unit test and just hope nothing breaks until a successor is found.

Comment: The nice way would be to dump the `class_prepared` crap from code and rename all your tables to the proper name.

Comment: @RickyA I didn't mean to say that. I meant to say that I want the existing unit tests to run in Django 1.7. (Though I'm sure you're wrong; everyone seems fine with leaving around these little hacks.) Also, I know that I will probably have to copy the tables....I was just hoping some expert had *another* little hack to postpone it.